# XML feed in joomla website

Tags: xml, joomla, hyperlink

I'm remaking this website in joomla
I got this [XML feed](https://www.managementboek.nl/code/affiliates/feed.php?affiliate=150&sort=7d&num=10) and i want it to show in the joomla website but i dont know how to use XML feed.
I have been searchin voor 2 days now and i really dont know how to do it.

This is the current [website](http://hrnetwerk.nl/hrm_boeken.php), it uses the XML feed to shoow all the book's

I don't know how to get/use xml feed in my joomla website.
Do you know if it's posible and how?

Thanks in advance

Comment: does that work in joomla? and how?